# How can I delete virtualenv with Django project from repository and add requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, django, github, repository, virtualenv

I pushed my virtualenv with Django project to github repository. I have found information that it wasn't the best solution. I noticed that community suggest adding file requirements.txt with pip freeze instead of virtualenv to github repository. So I would like to delete virtualenv and add such file. I wonder how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
$ git rm <your-virtualenv>
$ git status
$ git commit -m "commit-message"
$ git push
```

Now to disable these files to show up on `$ git status` create a .gitignore file.
or simply run below command from your project root:

```
$ echo "<your-virtualenv>" >> .gitignore
```

if your code is used from multiple device then push .gitignore.

Answer (score 2):

```
(env) $ git rm -r env
(env) $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
(env) $ git add requirements.txt
(env) $ git commit -m "Removed env dir. Added requirements.txt"
(env) $ git push origin master
```